# How do I change the Display Frequency on linux

Tags: linux, display

I want to change the display's frequency from 60hz to 50hz, on a fedora core 9 box, anyone know how to do this?

Thank you

Comment: What desktop environment?

Answer (score 2):

Expand the **Monitor** section of /etc/X11/xorg.conf to look something like this:

```
Section "Monitor"
        Identifier   "Monitor0"
        VendorName   "Monitor Vendor"
        ModelName    "Monitor Model"
        HorizSync    30-107
        VertRefresh  48-120
EndSection
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a new modeline to the `Monitor` section of `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` with the desired frequency. Use `cvt` to generate the appropriate modeline.